# Cosine Similarity between two words in a context in Python

Tags: python, cosine-similarity

I am trying to perform in python the cosine similarity between two words which are in a dataset of texts (each text represents a tweet). I want to evaluate the similarity based on the context where they are placed.

I have set a code like the following:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

corpus = dataset
// corpus is a list of texts (in this case is a list of tweets)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
trsfm = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
sims = cosine_similarity(trsfm, trsfm)
counts = count_vect.fit_transform(corpus)
pd.DataFrame(trsfm.toarray(), columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names(), index = corpus)
vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

The result is the similarity between the texts but I want the similarity between two words.

So, wow can I obtain the similarity between two words and not between two texts?
For instance, I want the similarity between these couple of words: {["covid","vaccine"], ["work","covid"], ["environment","pollution"]}.

In addition, I want to represet these words in a cartesian plane in order to display graphically the distances amongst them. So I need to calculate their cartesian coordinates.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: you need to use models like BERT.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Would you mind to share with me some link or docs which can help me? I've been looking for two days about solution but I found only similarity between two documents or sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some useful links you can get start with -

```
https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/word_embeddings  
https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805  
https://machinelearningmastery.com/what-are-word-embeddings/  
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/word-embeddings-count-word2veec/
```

Comment: JAbr thank you very much for your advices, thanks to your links I figured it out, I did it and it works.